# The maximum depth Apollo astronauts dug into lunar regolith?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, regolith

Almost on every mission the astronauts did some digging, but how deep did they reach? According to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regolith#Moon):

> The regolith is generally from 4 to 5 metres thick in *mare* areas and
>   from 10 to 15 metres in the older highland regions.[3] Below this true
>   regolith is a region of blocky and fractured bedrock created by larger
>   impacts, which is often referred to as the "megaregolith".

So did they ever see what was beneath the regolith?

Comment: Yes, but when it turned out to be plywood, they... :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> So did they ever see what was beneath the regolith?

No. The Apollo program sent a deep core drill ("deep": 3 meters) on Apollo 15, 16, and 17. The deepest sample was 292 centimeters during Apollo 17.

See [Apollo 17 Samples 70001 to 70006 Deep Drill Core](http://curator.jsc.nasa.gov/lunar/lsc/A17drill.pdf) for details on the sample.